# The question mark looks new to me

Tags: java, android, xml, android-layout

This

```
<TextView
xmlns:android=”http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android”
android:id=”@+id/separator”
android:layout_width=”fill_parent”
android:layout_height=”wrap_content”
android:gravity=”center”
style=”?android:attr/listSeparatorTextViewStyle” />
```

or this

```
   <item name="android:textColor">?textColorSecondary</item>
```

Sometimes I see the question mark in the xml node's content like that, and I don't know what it is for, no documentation right ?

Comment: `?` is common for query strings.  In the context of Android and XML,   I'm not sure entirely.

Comment: That references a resource in the current theme: http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/accessing-resources.html#ReferencesToThemeAttributes

Comment: @full.stack.ex You should post this link and quote the relevant passage as an answer. (I was going to, but you beat me to it.)

Comment: @Sam, thanks; it's answered now :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `?` references a resource in the current theme, it's decribed in Developer's Guide [Accessing Resources](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/accessing-resources.html#ReferencesToThemeAttributes):

> A style attribute resource allows you to reference the value of an attribute in the currently-applied theme. Referencing a style attribute allows you to customize the look of UI elements by styling them to match standard variations supplied by the current theme, instead of supplying a hard-coded value. Referencing a style attribute essentially says, "use the style that is defined by this attribute, in the current theme."
>
> To reference a style attribute, the name syntax is almost identical to
>   the normal resource format, but instead of the at-symbol (@), use a question-mark (?), and the resource type portion is optional. For instance:
>
> ```
> ?[<package_name>:][<resource_type>/]<resource_name>
> ```

Comment: Normally posting a link to the documentation _only_, isn't a good "answer". But since the question asked for documentation and an explanation, this is great. (Upvote from me.)